# Доступ к меняющимся значениям скрипта другого объекта Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть один объект, на нем есть скрипт с public значениями.
Есть другой объект, на нем скрипт, который должен брать некоторые переменные из первого и их выводить.

Сейчас это выглядит так

```
void Start()
{
AxisX = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Joystick").GetComponent<FloatSpeedXYJoystick>().AxisX;
}

private void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Label(new Rect(0, 0, 300, 30), "AxisX = " + AxisX.ToString("F3");
}
```

Он получает значения на старте, но они нулевые. Вероятно, дело в том что он их получает один раз?

Но ставить в Update функцию с FindGameObject и GetComponent - весьма нагрузочно.

Какое более простое решение получить изменяющиеся значения из скрипта другого объекта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать во втором скрипте ссылку не на поле AxisX(скорей всего это не ссылочный тип !?), а на компонент.

```
        // Назначить в редакторе.
        public FloatSpeedXYJoystick _AxisX;

        void Start()
        {
            // Или найти тут.
             if(_AxisX == null)
                _AxisX = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Joystick").
                GetComponent<FloatSpeedXYJoystick>()
        }

        private void OnGUI()
        {
           GUI.Label(new Rect(0, 0, 300, 30), "AxisX = " + 
           _AxisX.AxisX .ToString("F3");
        }
```

Comment: FloatSpeedXYJoystick - это скрипт. Какого рода должна быть переменная _Axis, чтобы получить доступ к скрипту? Я не знаю переменных вида Class или Script в Unity.

Comment: @Dmitrii , я в ответе уже написал. Скрипт - это и есть класс(тип).